# Sorting inner tags in nested XML using XSLT

Tags: xml, xslt

My XML:

```
<List>
    <Item name="B" name2="cyprus">
        <ItemID value="ID_B"/>
        <InnerList>
            <InnerItem description="porto"><more_nested_data></more_nested_data></InnerItem>
            <InnerItem description="c#"><more_nested_data></more_nested_data></InnerItem>
        </InnerList>
    </Item>
    <Item name="B" name2="alele">
        <ItemID value="ID_B"/>
        <InnerList>
            <InnerItem description="porto"><more_nested_data></more_nested_data></InnerItem>
            <InnerItem description="c#"><more_nested_data></more_nested_data></InnerItem>
        </InnerList>
    </Item>
    <Item name="A" name2="alele">
        <ItemID value="ID_A"/>
        <InnerList>
            <InnerItem description="basic"><more_nested_data></more_nested_data></InnerItem>
            <InnerItem description="algarve"><more_nested_data></more_nested_data></InnerItem>
        </InnerList>
    </Item>
</List>
```

I want to sort it by `Item.name`, `Item.name2`. I also want to sort `InnerItem` in `InnerList` by `description` attribute.

Desired outcome:

```
<List>
<Item name="A" name2="alele">
    <ItemID value="ID_A"/>
    <InnerList>
        <InnerItem description="algarve"><more_nested_data></more_nested_data></InnerItem>
        <InnerItem description="basic"><more_nested_data></more_nested_data></InnerItem>        
    </InnerList>
</Item>
<Item name="B" name2="alele">
    <ItemID value="ID_B"/>
    <InnerList>
        <InnerItem description="c#"><more_nested_data></more_nested_data></InnerItem>
        <InnerItem description="porto"><more_nested_data></more_nested_data></InnerItem>        
    </InnerList>
</Item>
<Item name="B" name2="cyprus">
    <ItemID value="ID_B"/>
    <InnerList>
        <InnerItem description="c#"><more_nested_data></more_nested_data></InnerItem>
        <InnerItem description="porto"><more_nested_data></more_nested_data></InnerItem>
    </InnerList>
</Item>
</List>
```

My XSL:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" omit-xml-declaration="yes"/>

  <xsl:template match="@* | node()">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

      <xsl:template match="List">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="Item">
        <xsl:sort select="@name"/>
        <xsl:sort select="@name2"/>
      </xsl:apply-templates>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

It does order the `Item` correctly. How do I go about sorting `InnerItem`?

I could add this `for-each`:

```
 <xsl:template match="List">
    <xsl:for-each select="Item">
        <xsl:for-each select="InnerList">
            <xsl:for-each select="InnerItem">
                <xsl:sort select="@description"/>
                <xsl:copy-of select="."/>
            </xsl:for-each>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:template>
```

but then I lose my XML structure and getting this:

```
<InnerItem description="c#">
  <more_nested_data/>
</InnerItem><InnerItem description="porto">
  <more_nested_data/>
</InnerItem><InnerItem description="c#">
  <more_nested_data/>
</InnerItem><InnerItem description="porto">
  <more_nested_data/>
</InnerItem><InnerItem description="algarve">
  <more_nested_data/>
</InnerItem><InnerItem description="basic">
  <more_nested_data/>
</InnerItem>
```

Any hint what is the right approach appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add another template:

```
<xsl:template match="InnerList">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="InnerItem">
            <xsl:sort select="@description"/>
        </xsl:apply-templates>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
```